# stop settimeout incremention for an animated div

Tags: javascript, animation, settimeout

I have a function which increments the css quality of the position of a div layer and need it to stop when it reaches a certain amount of percentage to either the right or left (depending on the layer). 
I have tried to do an if statement with a greater than operator, but does not seem to work. Here is the code in full:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stelucir</title>
<style>
body {
  background-color: white;
}
#bg-right {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

var header = null; // object
var about = null; // object
var blog = null; // object
var forum = null; // object
var chat = null; // object
var home = null; // object

function doMove() {
  header.style.right = parseInt(header.style.right)+1+'%';
  about.style.left = parseInt(about.style.left)+1+'%';
  blog.style.right = parseInt(blog.style.right)+1+'%';
  forum.style.left = parseInt(forum.style.left)+1+'%';
  chat.style.right = parseInt(chat.style.right)+1+'%';
  home.style.left = parseInt(home.style.left)+1+'%';
  setTimeout(doMove,30); // call doMove in 20msec
}

function init() {
  header = document.getElementById('header');
  about = document.getElementById('about');
  blog = document.getElementById('blog');
  forum = document.getElementById('forum');
  chat = document.getElementById('chat');
  home = document.getElementById('home'); 
  doMove(); // start animating
}

window.onload = init;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bg-right"></div>
<div id="header" style = "position:absolute;right:25%;font-size:80px;">Stelucir</div>
<div id="about" style = "position:absolute;left:40%;font-  size:40px;top:90px;color:white;">About</div>
<div id="blog" style = "position:absolute;right:40%;font-size:40px;top:130px;">Blog</div>
<div id="forum" style = "position:absolute;left:40%;font-size:40px;top:170px;color:white;">Forum</div>
<div id="chat" style = "position:absolute;right:40%;font-size:40px;top:210px;">Chat</div>
<div id="home" style = "position:absolute;left:40%;font-size:40px;top:250px;color:white;">Home</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is this `if` statement?

Comment: I said I tried it and it didn't work, I didn't say I included it in the code, I was mentioning to save suggestions of something I had already tried.

Comment: Well, an `if` statement is almost certainly going to be involved.  It is generally useful to include what you tried that didn't work so people can explain how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global boolean.  Start it at true, and when it reaches whatever point you want, set it to false.  In doMove check to see that this is true, and if it's false simply return.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` returns a handle on the timer. you can then call `clearTimeout()` on this handle to stop the timer.

Make a global variable to store this

```
var timer = null;
...
function doMove() {
    ...
    timer = setTimeout(...);
}
//somewhere else
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would more suggest using an interval instead of multiple setTimeout call. Also both setInterval and setTimeout return a reference which can be used to stop them using clearInterval(ref) or clearTimeout(ref);

Here is a little fiddle that animate a box to the right and stop when it is there.

http://jsfiddle.net/JV35w/1/

```
var elem = document.getElementById('foo'),
    startX = 0,
    endX = 400,
    move = function() {
        elem.style.left = startX + 'px';
        startX += 10;
        if (endX === startX) {
            startX = 0;
            clearInterval(t);
        };
    },
    doMove = function() {
        t = setInterval(move);
    },
    t;

doMove();​
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval